# Example on how to use Vysper xmpp with smack

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack, apache-vysper

Anyone could point an example, tutorial, doc, etc, about how to use Vysper to serve xmpp. I managed to start Vysper but cant find anything on how to exchange messages.
I'm trying to create a chat app, much like whatsapp, google talk and so on.
I dont want to use Google Cloud Management.
I would like configure myself a xmpp server.

Others options besides Vysper would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a specialist in the XMPP but I was writing a small project - communicator based on `Smack` and `OpenFire server`.

From my own experience I can recommend You using the OpenFire server.
Here is the example of Communicator which is based on Smack and OpenFire: https://github.com/mack94/Komunikator---Wiadomosci/

*If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask me*